# Including all of one value and filtering another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I would like to include all issues with every status, but include those with a status of 'Closed' only when the DateResolved is within the last 5 days. Include all of the other status values where DateResolved IS NULL.

Data:

```
IssueStatus DateResolved
Closed      7/25/2021
Closed      7/26/2021
Closed      7/1/2021
In Progress 
Deferred    
Deferred
```

This returns only IssueStatus = 'Closed' within last 5 days.

```
SELECT IssueStatus, DateResolved FROM TABLE
WHERE IssueStatus IN ('Closed','In Progress','Deferred')
AND DateResolved >= DATEADD(d, -5, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

Desired results:

```
IssueStatus DateResolved
Closed      7/25/2021
Closed      7/26/2021
In Progress 
Deferred    
Deferred
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If don't wish to explicitly list the IssueStatus's to include then you could try something like this

```
SELECT IssueStatus, DateResolved 
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE (IssueStatus='Closed'
       AND DateResolved >= DATEADD(d, -5, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)))
      OR IssueStatus<>'Closed';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an `OR`:

```sql
SELECT IssueStatus, DateResolved FROM TABLE
WHERE IssueStatus IN ('In Progress','Deferred')
   OR (IssueStatus = 'Closed'
  AND  DateResolved >= DATEADD(d, -5, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest `WHERE` clause is probably:

```
WHERE DateResolved >= DATEADD(day, -5, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) OR
      IssueStatus <> 'Closed';
```

You don't explicitly need to check for "Closed" for the last five days.  In other words, you can phrase what you want as:  "All rows with a resolution date in the last five days or non-Closed issues".